# bash export a variable that has the key and value

Tags: bash, export

I'm trying to export a variable in this manner:

```
P="A="X""
echo $P
P=X

export $$P   <- can't get this to work, tried a bunch of permutations
```

Desired out put is then to be effectively 'export A=X'
In the example I want to 'export P=X' to be the command I run, however I cannot get it to work correctly

Comment: You have a command named `P=X`?

Comment: `export P` no `$`

Comment: There are several confusions here, and I'm not really sure what you're actuallt trying to do. You seem to be trying to use `P` for two different things: an environment (i.e. exported) variable with the value `X`, and also a shell (non-exported) variable describing what you want to export (with the value `P="X"`, maybe?). These are different and incompatible things; use two different variable names!

Comment: updated the post to add some clarity, but yes that was a bad example using P twice. 

export P does not work

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
P="A=\"X"\"
echo $P
A="X"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ P='A="This is a test"'
$ echo "$P"
A="This is a test"
$ eval export "$P"
$ echo "$A"
This is a test
```